# Double click event is not working If the content is empty

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ondoubleclick

I am using double click event on a `<span></span>` to toggle visibility of control in my MVC application.

```
<span ondblclick="myFunction()">m.Value</span>
```

> where m is my model.

In the above code, span content is `m.Value`, which can be empty.

When `m.Value` is empty, `ondblclick()` event is not fired. Is there any workaround for this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a span is empty it doesn't have any width or height, therefore you can't click it. 
To resolve this you can set your span do display block or inline-block and set a specific width, height:

```
span.model {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%; /*or 100px, ... */
   height: 50%; /* or 100px, ... */
}
```

Comment: for debug purpose you can apply span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: red;
    }